# Laravel search results to contain HTML and rendered in Flutter UI

Tags: html, laravel, parsing, flutter

I've got a flutter app that connects to a database built on Laravel. In essence, our users will have a profile, and their profile will match with certain kinds of posts. When these posts are matched on and displayed in the frontend (I think they are returned as JSON but not 100% sure), we want certain fields from these results to contain some html that gets rendered in our Flutter UI.

Things like ul,  li, line break, p, and maybe bolding. Nothing too major. What would be the right way to read in these text fields in order to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are 2 possible solutions.

**First solution:**

Try adding the following dependency in pubspec.ymal

```
dependencies:
 flutter_html_view: ^0.5.11
```

And use it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_html_view/flutter_html_view.dart';

String html = '<body>Hello world! <a href="#">HTML5 rocks!</a> <ul><li>test</li></ul>';

new HtmlView(
  data: html,
  baseURL: "", // optional, type String
  onLaunchFail: (url) { // optional, type Function
    print("launch $url failed");
  },
  scrollable: false
)
```

The supported tags are:

- p
- em
- b
- img
- video
- h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6

### Note

This plugin converts some of the html tags to flutter widgets
This plugin doesn't support rendering full html code (there is no built in support for web rendering in flutter)

**Second Solution:**

Basically you need to convert your html to Markdown.

```
dependencies
  html2md: "^0.3.2"
  flutter_markdown: "^0.2.0"
```

The code is something like

```
//importing packages
import 'package:html2md/html2md.dart' as html2md;
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

// get the html string
static String html = '<h1>This is heading 1</h1> <h2>This is heading 2</h2><h3>This is heading 3</h3><h4>This is heading 4</h4><h5>This is heading 5</h5><h6>This is heading 6</h6><img alt="Test Image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RHLknisJ-Sg/maxresdefault.jpg" /><p>This paragraph contains a lot of lines in the source code, but the browser ignores it.</p>';

//convert it
String markdown = html2md.convert(html);
```

To use it on the widget, just do:

```
new MarkdownBody(
  data: markdown,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

highly recommend using [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) plugin

as they explain in website you can load and render you html with :

```
var document = parse('<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!');
```